# How to add trendline to scatter plot in .net charting?

Tags: charts

I use a scatter plot to visualize the correlation of weight and height for male and female. I do this with .net charting:

```
chart.Type = ChartType.Scatter;
chart.DefaultSeries.Type = SeriesType.Marker;

SeriesCollection SC = new SeriesCollection();

Series s1 = new Series();
s1.Elements.Add(GetElements(female));

Series s2 = new Series();
s2.Elements.Add(GetElements(male));

SC.Add(s1);
SC.Add(s2);
```

How can I add a first degree trendline for both series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the math method `StatisticalEngine.LeastSquaresEstimateY()` for this that takes a series for which the trendline should be calculated. It generates a new series which you can style as usual:

```
Series s3 = StatisticalEngine.LeastSquaresEstimateY("Series 1", s1);
s3.Type = SeriesType.Line;

Series s4 = StatisticalEngine.LeastSquaresEstimateY("Series 2", s2);
s4.Type = SeriesType.Line;

SC.Add(s3);
SC.Add(s4);
```